# How to download displayed data from VF page into an excel file without querying again?

Tags: apex, visualforce, contenttype

I have a VF page in which I am displaying data to users. The data is fetched from an external system. I wish to have a download button on the VF page so that users will be able to download the data in csv format.

On researching, I found out that I can redirect to a VF page that defines `contentType` and the file will get downloaded automatically. The problem is that another call will need to be made on that VF page. Is there a way by which I can download the data without making another call to fetch the data?

### **Example Code**

**Controller Code**

```java
public class ExportContactsDemoController {

    public List<Contact> lstContact {set;get;}
   
    public ExportContactsDemoController(){
        lstContact = [Select Id, Name, Email, Phone From Contact Limit 10];   
    }
    
}
```

**ShowContactsDemo - This VF page displays data to the users:**

```html
<apex:page controller="ExportContactsDemoController" cache="true">
    <apex:form id="f1">
        <head>
            <script>
            function ExportToExcel(){
                confirm('Are you sure you want to export an excel ?');
                window.open('/apex/ExportContactsDemo'); 
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <apex:pageBlock title="10 Contacts">
                <apex:commandButton value="Export to Excel" onclick="ExportToExcel();" oncomplete=""/>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstContact}" var="objContact">
                    <apex:column value="{!objContact.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!objContact.Email}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!objContact.Phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </body>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**ExportContactsDemo - This VF page uses the same controller as previous page and downloads the data**

```html
<apex:page controller="ExportContactsDemoController" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#ContactsData.xls">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstContact}" var="objContact">
            <apex:column value="{!objContact.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!objContact.Email}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!objContact.Phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

In this example, the query present inside the controller is fired twice. Is there a way I can use the data fetched by the first query and download it without querying again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by initially keeping the `contentType=""` and changing it to `contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#report.xls"` when the export button was clicked.

I used a flag to change the `contentType` as follows:

`contentType="{!IF(isExport = true, 'application/vnd.ms-excel#report.xls', '')}"`

This eliminated the use of another VF page and also eliminated the need for a second query.

### Working Example

**VF Page Code**

```html
<apex:page controller="ExportContactsDemoController" cache="true" contentType="{!IF(isExport = true, 'application/vnd.ms-excel#report.xls', '')}">
    <apex:form id="f1">
            <apex:pageBlock title="10 Contacts">
                <apex:commandbutton id="button" value="Export" action="{!getExport}" reRender=""/>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstContact}" var="objContact">
                    <apex:column value="{!objContact.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!objContact.Email}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!objContact.Phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Code:**

```java
public class ExportContactsDemoController {

    public List<Contact> lstContact {set;get;}
    public boolean isExport{get; set;}
   
    public ExportContactsDemoController(){
        isExport= false;
        lstContact = [Select Id, Name, Email, Phone From Contact Limit 10];   
    }
    
    public PageReference getExport() {
        isExport= true;
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: P.S. You don't need to return a null pagereference, it's sufficient to change the action method to just: `public void getExport() { isExport= true; }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can avoid the second query, but you won't be able to open it in a new window. To do this, redirect from the first page to the second through an `apex:` component that can redirect via an `action`. When you do this, Visualforce will pass the controllers between pages and retain the View State of the page, thus not calling the controller again.

I've written a very simple example you can follow along with:

## commonController.apxc

```
public class commonController {
    public String helloWorld { get; set; }
    public commonController() {
        // Do logic only if initializing from scratch
        if(helloWorld == null) {
            helloWorld = 'Hello World';
        }
    }
}
```

## page1.vfp

```
<apex:page controller="commonController">
    {!helloWorld}
    <br />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Page.page2)}" value="View as PDF" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## page2.vfp

```
<apex:page controller="commonController" renderAs="pdf">
    {!helloWorld}
</apex:page>
```

I've intentionally made this a PDF so it can be as simple as possible, but you can do this sort of redirect easily for any type of content type that's supported.

You could also use a merge field for `renderAs`, simply changing from HTML to Excel when you change a variable, etc, although I agree that keeping the pages separate is usually a better idea.

A slightly less popular approach is to use a temporary record or file somewhere in Saleforce (e.g. a ContentVersion), which allows transfer of data that would otherwise exceed the view state of 135kb.

Comment: ThankYou for the answer! I added the line `<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Page.ExportContactsDemo)}" value="Export to Excel" />` in the `ShowContactsDemo` VF page (Rest of the code is present in the question). I faced 2 problems. 1) After clicking the button, the complete screen turns blue within 2 seconds (Like the background color of the VF page). 2) I put a debug statement in the constructor of the controller and I found that it's executing twice. It means that the query is also executing twice. What am I doing wrong? Please guide. Thanks again!

Comment: In the example given in the question, the only difference between the two VF pages is that one page has `contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#ContactsData.xls"`. Is there a way by which we can initially keep the `contentType=""` and change it to `contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#ContactsData.xls"` after the button is clicked? In this case, there will be no need for another VF page.

Comment: @Koustubh (a) Hmm, okay, that's interesting. I didn't realize the constructor was called again. I did some testing and fixed this (you'll see the edit in a moment). (b) Yes, you could use a merge field for contentType, as you can with most other properties. Just have the button call a method to update a variable and change the content type.

Comment: Merge field approach worked. Thank You for the guidance!

Comment: I have a related question. Can you please guide me?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330888/how-can-a-vf-page-be-attached-to-email-as-a-pdf-attachment-in-landscape-format