# How to use merge field for CSS in a VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, merge-field

I have a VF page that I display to the user and also send it as a PDF email attachment. I wish to use normal font size while showing the VF page but smaller font size while sending the VF page as an email attachment. I tried to implement this requirement through merge field but it's not working.

**Code**

Flag `reduceFont` will control the font size on the VF page.

```html
<apex:pageBlockTable style="{!IF( reduceFont = true, 'width:100%;font-size: 90%;', 'width:100%;')}" >
```

Declared the flag in the controller.

```java
public boolean reduceFont{get; set;}
```

Initialized the flag to `false` in the constructor.

```java
reduceFont = false;
```

Used the following code to set the flag `reduceFont` to `true` and send an email.

```java
public PageReference EmailRateSheet() {        
        
        PageReference rateProfile =  ApexPages.currentPage(); //get the current page reference
        rateProfile.setRedirect(true); //set the redirect property to true to avoid the page resubmission warning
        rateProfile.getParameters().put('reduceFont','true'); //set the flag reduceFont to true
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment(); //create attachment
        attachment.setFileName('RateProfile for ' + CustomerRec.Name + '.pdf'); //set the file name of attachment
        if(!test.isRunningTest()){ //The method getContentAsPDF() cannot be used for test methods. More Info- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm
            attachment.setBody(rateProfile.getContentAsPDF()); //set the pdf version of the page in body of the attachment.  
        }else{
            attachment.setBody(blob.toPDF('Test class Running'));
        }
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); //create SingleEmailMessage object
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } ); //set the attachment to the email
        message.setSubject('Rate sheet for ' + CustomerRec.Name); //set subject of the email
        message.setHTMLBody('Hi '+ userInfo.getFirstName() + ', <p>' +' The Rate sheet for <b>' + CustomerRec.Name + '</b> is attached. <p> Regards,<P> Salesforce Team'); //set body of the email
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { UserInfo.getUserEmail() } ); //set the email address of the logged-in user as recipient address
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } ); //send the email
        return rateProfile; //return the page reference. If you return null, page resubmission warning will appear on refreshing the page.
}
```

The above method is not working. The font size does not get reduced in the PDF.

I tried setting `reduceFont = true` in the method `EmailRateSheet()` but that didn't work too. What am I doing wrong? Please guide. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In your PDF page's constructor, read the reduceFont parameter and set it appropriately:

```
reduceFont = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('reduceFont') == 'true';
```

Alternatively, use the `@media print` CSS media query:

```
@media print {
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer! I tried out both methods. 
**Method 1:** I set the `reduceFont` parameter appropriately. It is not working for PDF. I am able to reduce the font size of VF page by returning page reference after setting `rateProfile.getParameters().put('reduceFont','true');` but it's not working on the PDF email attachment. I am not sure why. It may be due to `rateProfile.getContentAsPDF()`.                                        **Method 2:** I tried setting `@media print {
  font-size: 90%;
}` in <style> tag as well as in CSS static resource. Both didn't work.

Comment: I also tried applying merge field on stylesheet as follows: `<apex:stylesheet value="{!IF( reduceFont = true, '{!$Resource.ReduceFontPDF}', '')}"/>`. In this case, the resource is not getting applied because of extra quotes. If I remove the quotes, I get a syntax error.

Comment: @SFdev You don't use merge field syntax inside a merge field, it would be `value="{!IF(reduceFont, $Resource.ReduceFontPDF, '')}"`

Comment: @SFdev Also, if you've already set `renderAs="pdf"` on the page, you don't need `getContentAsPDF()`, just use the normal `getContent()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried setting the `<apex:stylesheet>` as suggested by you. It did not reduce the font size of PDF file. Also, I have not used `renderAs="pdf"` on the VF page because I am displaying the VF page to users and sending the same page as email PDF attachment on click of a button.

Comment: I put a debug statement in the constructor and found out that the constructor is not getting called while sending the email. This means that `rateProfile.getContentAsPDF()` is not calling the constructor. Hence it's not setting the flag `reduceFont` to `true` even though it's set as a parameter while creating the PageReference object. This is the reason why merge field is not working while sending email.

Comment: @SFdev Keep in mind that a getContent or getContentAsPDF is a callout, which means you get TWO logs (one for the code you call, one for the VF page). Make sure you're checking the right logs.

Comment: Yes, I got 2 logs. I checked them both. The debug statement of the constructor is not present in both the logs. Also, the size of both the logs is smaller than that of the VF page log that gets generated after refreshing the page.