# How to take input in a VF page that also needs to be rendered as a PDF with the help of getContentAsPDF()?

Tags: apex, visualforce, getcontentaspdf

I have a table on a VF page that displays 3 columns.

Last column of the table is defined as follows:

```html
<apex:column headerValue="New Value">  
    <apex:inputText value="{!RateParam.AttribValue}" id="Input1"  disabled="{!RateParam.disableInput}"/> 
</apex:column>
```

I am emailing a PDF version of this VF page to the user by making use of `getContentAsPDF()`. In the PDF received, I find that the last column is empty.

The other columns of the table are not empty in the PDF. They are defined as follows:

```html
<apex:column headerValue="Attribute" value="{!RateParam.AttribType}" />
```

Is it the case that `<apex:inputText>` does not work with `getContentAsPDF()`? If so, what alternative is the best to take input from the user and also render the page as a PDF using `getContentAsPDF()`?

I tried other ways to take input such as:

```
<input id="Input1" type="text" value="{!RateParam.AttribValue}" />
```

```
<apex:input value="{!RateParam.AttribValue}" id="Input1"/>
```

Both the methods didn't work.

Please guide. Thank You!

**Code of table:**

```html
            <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Rate Parameters"  columns="1" rendered="{!RateParamList.size!=0}" collapsible="True">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RateParamList}"  var="RateParam" id="RateParameters" style="width:100%;" cellPadding="4" border="1">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Attribute" value="{!RateParam.AttribType}" />  
                    <apex:Column headerValue="Existing Value" value="{!RateParam.OldAttribValue}" />                                 
                    <apex:column headerValue="New Value">  
                        <apex:inputText value="{!RateParam.AttribValue}" id="Input1"  disabled="{!RateParam.disableInput}"/> 
                    </apex:column>    
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```